# Locale language reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning redux by doing a small project. Everything is working fine, but I need to know how I can refactor such code. For this situation, it might be good to use `if conditions` like I have done, but what if I need to handle 7-8 languages? It won't be viable to use `else if for 7 times`. What is the proper way to handle such situation? Is it the right place to ask such question here?

```
import { FRENCH } from '../../public/messages/fr';
import { ENGLISH } from '../../public/messages/en';

const initialState = {
  lang: FRENCH.lang,
  messages: FRENCH.messages
};
export const localeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOCALE_SELECTED':
    if (action.locale === 'fr') {
      return { ...initialState, lang: FRENCH.lang, messages: FRENCH.messages };
    } else if (action.locale === 'en') {
      return { ...initialState, lang: ENGLISH.lang, messages: ENGLISH.messages };
    } break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest your case statements if you want:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOCALE_SELECTED':
      switch (action.locale) {
        case 'fr':
          return { ...initialState, lang: FRENCH.lang, messages: FRENCH.messages };
        default:
          return { ...initialState, lang: ENGLISH.lang, messages: ENGLISH.messages };
      }
      break;

    default:
      return state;
}
```

or for readability (especially where there are many cases) break the sub case statements out into separate functions (this is moving towards 'composed reducers' where the state is derived from multiple reducers, which can also be at different levels in the hierarchy).

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOCALE_SELECTED':
     return localeReducer(action);
      break;

    default:
      return state; 
}
```

Comment: Which one do you prefer, in situation where you have to check for more conditions?

Comment: I prefer breaking things up(!); reads better, the reducer can focus on a particular part of the state and it's easier to test.

Comment: Of course if there number of cases is relatively low breaking it up can be overkill.On the subject of combing reducers to build up the state have a look at this: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html